# Joomla articles are opened in main page

Tags: module, joomla, hide, mainwindow, joomla-article

There is a slide on my main page. When I click on articles which are shown in slide, the article is opened in same main page.

Everything remains the same and the article is shown in middle of everything. How can I fix this to show only article?

I'm using Joomla version 2.5

Comment: Could you please share your website here...? Then we get a good idea..?

Answer (score 0):

My Joomla knowledge is a little rusty, but from what I can remember, it looks like all your modules are appearing on every page, not just the homepage as you intended. There are 2 ways to handle this:

1. Go into the module settings and make sure only "home" is selected from the menu-item box.
2. In your homepage template, check whether you're using the "frontpage" component (option=com_frontpage). If so, display the homepage module containers, otherwise just display the content.

Comment: it is joomla 2.5 by the way. is it about url-rewriting or something?

Answer (score 0):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307

This is a known issue with Joomla. If you click on an internal link it will display all the modules on the page. The solution is to use the advanced module manager - link above to control what pages the modules display on

Answer (score 0):

*Solution migrated from question to an answer*:

> I gave it a shot with advanced module manager; there was an error
> while installing:
>
> > NNI_NOT_COMPATIBLE_PHP
>
> It was useless afterward. I found an article about this issue which
> solved my problem:
> https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_module_display_when_linking_to_an_article_with_no_menu_item
>
> Now each article opens without unwanted modules around.
>
> The cause of this problem is articles being unlinked to any menu item.
> Creating a hidden menu and adding articles as sub menu item solves
> issue.